# org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException on POST request in ManyToOne Bidirectional relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to create a new user using the following POST request on **/addNewUser** endpoint: -

**Post Request**

```
{
    "username"   : "abc",
    "password"   : "123",
    "enabled"    : "true",
    "authorities": [{ 
                        "authority" : "ROLE_USER" 
                    }]
}
```

**UserController** class: -

```
@PostMapping("/addNewUser")
    public UserModel addNewUser(@RequestBody UserModel user) {
        return userService.addNewUser(user);
    }
```

**UserService** class: -

```
public UserModel addNewUser(UserModel user) {
        return userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
    }
```

**UserRepository** interface

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserModel, String> {

}
```

But I'm getting the following exception: -

```
2020-04-30 21:14:00.441 ERROR 23653 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: null value in column "authority" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, null).
2020-04-30 21:14:00.450 ERROR 23653 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [authority]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "authority" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, null).
```

**UserModel** class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserModel {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private boolean enabled;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<AuthoritiesModel> authorities;

    //getters and setters
}
```

**AuthoritiesModel** class: -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "authorities")
public class AuthoritiesModel implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="username", unique = false, nullable=false)
    private UserModel user;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "authority") 
    private String authority;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Initially, I thought there was some problem with my post request or the deserialization by the Jackson API, so I printed out the values of the UserModel fields in the controller method and all the values were set properly including the AuthoritiesModel. But when I try to persist the UserModel Object it throws the exception.

**Update 1:**

If I post a request without authorities it doesn't throw any exception but I get authorities as null in response.

**Post Request**

```
{
    "username"   : "abc",
    "password"   : "123",
    "enabled"    : "true"
}
```

**Post Response**

```
{
    "username": "abc",
    "password": "123",
    "enabled": true,
    "authorities": null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I begin to answer let me clear the obvious problem I didn't have: -

First, I thought that hibernate wraps the code with a proxy and the Jackson binding code also uses reflection and not call traditional getters and setters. Also, Hibernate essentially uses flags to determine if an object has been touched by looking to see what methods have been called through getters and setters, the fields for the one to many mapping don't appear to be because they were set through reflection. So I tried to put some simple system.out.printlns in the setters and saw that they are in fact are getting called. So this wasn't the problem in my case.

Secondly, I used the unit test and not do a POST request and call the method in the service tier directly and see if the write to the database occurs. But it didn't.

**So, the answer was obvious: -**

**The service tier should call the two repository tier objects. Service tier objects should be one-to-many repository objects. It is standard practice and one that often used when implementing across web services too.**

But I didn't get it why we need to add a separate call just to add the things already defined in our entities and their mapping. I'm not sure if I did or understood something wrong but I feel that hibernate should be smart enough to handle such cases. Ideally, it should persist the parent object first and then use our mapping to fetch the details from the database and persist the child object according to it. But the problem here is that you are asking it to know that the activity in the object isn't in the database and should be created AND tied to that UserModel and it seems like a cascade should do that, but it won't.

Answer (score 0):

The `AuthoritiesModel` does not have a `UserModel` set on it when the request body is deserialized.

You might try something like:

```
public UserModel addNewUser(UserModel user) {
    List<AuthorityModel> authorities = user.getAuthorities();
    authorities.stream().forEach(authority -> authority.setUser(user);
    return userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried this approach. But it doesn't work. As I have already mentioned in the question, I too thought that was deserialization problem but then I printed the UserModel fields on the console and they are perfectly set including the List<AuthoritiesModel> and the UserModel inside AuthoritiesModel. I think I have some issue with my mapping or something which is why JPA is not able to persist the AuthoritiesModel (child) entity successfully.

Comment: Are the `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` on the correct fields?  According to this example, they should be reversed.
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

Comment: The annotations are correct because in my case, the owner of this relationship is the UserModel, a user can have multiple Authorities associated with it. Hence it is the UserModel which is the managed reference. Also, this helps to solve the infinite recursion problem when I try to fetch all the users along with their Authorities.

And if you reverse the annotations it will throw an exception while deserializing the request: -
back reference type (java.util.List) not compatible with managed type (com.test.testing.model.Authorities)